# What would be the best way to transfer my (small) SQL Server database between 2 locations?

Tags: sql-server, git, version-control

I am working on a project where I am the only person working on it. I am trying to do everything with "best practice" in mind as best I can.

I work on the project from 2 locations - work PC and home PC. I make regular commits to a Git repo, and keep both locations up to date this way.

Over the weekend I implemented a small SQL Server database with my app, came into work today and found that `.mdf` files were automatically on my `.gitignore`.

Done some digging, and seems that is how it should stay. I have looked into source controling the database, but everything seems to either point to expensive software, or some tool I can't fathom.

What would be the best way to keep not only the structure of that Database, but also the data contents of the database the same between both my home and work locations? Should I delete `.mdf` from source control and just do it that way? Or would it be better to do XYZ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to just backup at one location and restore in the other. You can do this backup and restore using the free SSMS or simply in code if you wish. You can zip the generated .bak file. That is one of the easiest ways.

You can also detach and attach mdf files but I find backup easier to manage.

Comment: Which is the latest, free version of SSMS? (Having problems downloading here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8961 at the moment). So I should backup then zip up the databse, push changes to repo, then pull off repo at new location, unzip and restore backup? Seems a lot more work than just push/pull!

Comment: Whatever the latest version of SQL server is, namely it is 2014 at this time. You can however download and use one that matches with the version you have. 
I wasn't thinking in the context of version control, which is more work for me to push/pull and lose my data on the click of an unindented "undo checkout" (I simply log on to my work computer to work remotely and prefer heaving source control by means of scheduled backups).

Answer (score 1):

More options:

You could create database creation/modification scripts with including of all data also. into insert/update statement. Or you could store data in csv and fill it by script. and store these script and csv data files in any version control tool.

Here is two modifications:

1. Scripts will delete existing database and then create it from scratch like in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).
2. Scripts, which can update any existing database version up to current version without deletion of data

The second way is more complex, but it can be the only way sometimes for enterprise level systems because of many versions in many environments and necessity to leave the test and production data untouched.

So I think 1st of proposed versions suits more to your case.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any "templates" around of the scripts that might be useful? And when would I run those scripts, after each pull from repo?

Comment: You could right-click on your database in management studio and choose task->generate scripts and then just choose scheme+data option for data and SQL server will create all necessary scripts automatically - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: And like with all other code - when you'll have a version of DB which you'd like to commit to the repository, then you can generate a script and commit it or modified scripts to your repository

Comment: In case if you choose the way of manual modification of scripts, you could split it to files related to exact DB objects - schemas, tables, functions and so on, for your convenience and then create a general script to apply all of these scripts in the correct sequence.

Comment: Then you can run this script anytime to create the actual database in any instance of MS SQL Server or even in sqlfiddle from your repository